# Symfony ModelListType Form with Query Filter

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have a Symfony 3.4 Form that I want to present as a ModelListType::class, allowing the user to choose an existing entity, add a new one or edit the one that is already selected.

So, like this:

```
          ->add('myClass', ModelListType::class, [
              'class' => MyClass::class,
              'required'  => true,
              'btn_add' => 'Create New',
              'btn_list' => 'Select from List',
              'btn_edit' => 'Edit Details',
              'btn_delete' => false
          ])
```

However, I want to apply a filter to the entity list, using something like the 'query' field available in ModelType.

```
      'query' => $myClassFilter,
```

It seems 'query' is not available for ModelListType.

Is there any way I can filter like this?

Comment: Well it seems that `ModelListType` uses the sonata admin of the target class to create the list. If you want to filter it you have to do it in the admin of`MyClass`. That means either with [filtering the list route](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/action_list.html#callback-filter) or by overriding the `createQuery` method of the admin. Of course things may get complicated if you need to filter for specific stuff - is this the case?

Comment: Did you figure this out?